# RaptureXML weird behaviour

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, xcode

I am getting an error (well it doesn't shows, just crashes out of app, no info on console)
that seems to happen whenever i call the method Iterate from RXML's rootXML:

```
-(void)valueSearch {
    //FIRST CONNECTION
    NSString *serverAddress = @"http://www.commix.com.br/clientes/grupoglobo/apple/valor.xml";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverAddress] 
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:10];
NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;

    response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

    //SECOND CONNECTION - Just an encapsulated form of the first, since i use it in other parts
    // of the code
    response = [self requestWithParameters:@"valor.xml"];

    //i just uncommented both. but actually only one (connection) runs.

    //Creation of the rooXML so i can grab the info i need
    RXMLElement *rootXML = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:response];
    //This array is where i'll keep the info from the files.
    //it`s deallocated at the end in dealloc
    searchResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //This is the culprit. Atleast it seems so, since putting NSLog before and after
    //revealed so.
    [rootXML iterate:@"valor" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *valor) {
        NSLog(@"valor: %@", [valor child:@"nome"].text);
        [searchResult addObject:[valor child:@"nome"].text];
    }];
}
```

The thing is, when i comment the `requestWithParameters`and use the normal non-encapsulated style (//FIRST CONNECTION) i don't get errors. But if i use the second, when the program reaches `[rootXML iterate: [...]]`it crashes there without warning.

using RaptureXML: https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML

It also happens in another part of the code:

```
-(void)vehicleSearch {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"idArray" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray *idArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSMutableString *serverAddress = (@"http://www.commix.com.br/clientes/grupoglobo/apple/modelo.php?marc=%@",[idArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverAddress] 
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:10];

NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

    RXMLElement *rootXML = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:response];
    searchResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [rootXML iterate:@"modelo" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *modelo) {
        NSLog(@"modelo: %@", [modelo child:@"nome"].text);
        [searchResult addObject:[modelo child:@"nome"].text];
    }];

    [idArray release];
}
```

Happens at the same line `[rootXML iterate:]`.

Sorry for leaks and stuff, i'm inexperienced (thats why i'm here), Thanks!

EDIT:
ACTUALLY the culprit is the line

```
NSMutableString *serverAddress = (@"http://www.commix.com.br/clientes/grupoglobo/apple/modelo.php?marc=%@",[idArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

if i pass the parameter directly, without variables, it works:

```
NSMutableString *serverAddress = (@"http://www.commix.com.br/clientes/grupoglobo/apple/modelo.php?marc=4");
```

it shows correctly.

Comment: I already tried removing the allocation of searchResult array (will remove it anyway) but didn't work. Also i think i just noticed i can eliminate "response"and call my custom request directly for elementFromXMLData. but first gotta fix this error!

Comment: Personally i prefer to get the xml myself(using ASIHTTPRequest) and feed it to the xml parser as a string/data. Afterwards i use TBXML(http://tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) as the xml parser, that is just a preference thing.

Comment: I used TBXML in an old project, but as you said, a preference thing... i started using RXML and it just felt smooth... until this.

Comment: OK, i found the REAL culprit, edited post.

Comment: Was idArray not initializing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `,[idArray objectAtIndex:0]` is an NSString?
Try to use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.commix.com.br/clientes/grupoglobo/apple/modelo.php?marc=%@",[idArray objectAtIndex:0]];`
```

Or even

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.commix.com.br/clientes/grupoglobo/apple/modelo.php?marc=%@",[[idArray objectAtIndex:0]stringValue]];
```

Comment: I found it by myself, but thats what i had to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
response = [self requestWithParameters:@"valor.xml"];
```

if `response` is a property use `self.response` otherwise you will have memory leak issues.

Comment: same applies for searchResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Change it to if(!self.searchResult) self.searchResult = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];